# Linq to Sql resizes varchar(x) parameters to varchar(8000)

Tags: vb.net, linq, visual-studio-2010

Looking for possible causes for the recent performance problems our server has had (SQL Server 2008), we found something curious: some of our systems use LINQ to SQL to perform `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` operations. Thing is, if the table has `varchar` fields, even if the DBML has those fields mapped as `varchar` with the same size the table field, Linq generates its query using `varchar(8000)` parameters. For example, let's say I have the next table:

```
SampleTable
-----------------------------------
Field1        int
Field2        smallint
Field3        varchar(15)
Field4        varchar(50)
```

And the DBML desing code for that table looks like this:

```
<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage:="_Field1", DbType:="Int NOT NULL")>  _
Public Property Field1() As Integer
    Get
        Return Me._Field1
    End Get
    Set
        If ((Me._Field1 = value)  _
                    = false) Then
            Me.OnField1Changing(value)
            Me.SendPropertyChanging
            Me._Field1 = value
            Me.SendPropertyChanged("Field1")
            Me.OnField1Changed
        End If
    End Set
End Property

<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage:="_Field2", DbType:="SmallInt NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey:=true)>  _
Public Property Field2() As Short
    Get
        Return Me._Field2
    End Get
    Set
        If ((Me._Field2 = value)  _
                    = false) Then
            Me.OnField2Changing(value)
            Me.SendPropertyChanging
            Me._Field2 = value
            Me.SendPropertyChanged("Field2")
            Me.OnField2Changed
        End If
    End Set
End Property

<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage:="_Field3", DbType:="VarChar(15) NOT NULL", CanBeNull:=false)>  _
Public Property Field3() As String
    Get
        Return Me._Field3
    End Get
    Set
        If (String.Equals(Me._Field3, value) = false) Then
            Me.OnField3Changing(value)
            Me.SendPropertyChanging
            Me._Field3 = value
            Me.SendPropertyChanged("Field3")
            Me.OnField3Changed
        End If
    End Set
End Property

<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage:="_Field4", DbType:="VarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull:=false)>  _
Public Property Field4() As String
    Get
        Return Me._Field4
    End Get
    Set
        If (String.Equals(Me._Field4, value) = false) Then
            Me.OnField4Changing(value)
            Me.SendPropertyChanging
            Me._Field4 = value
            Me.SendPropertyChanged("Field4")
            Me.OnField4Changed
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

In my program, the method that inserts a row in that table has this code:

```
Public Sub InsertOnSampleTable(ByVal intValueForField1 As Integer, ByVal shortValueForField2 As Short, ByVal stringValueForField3 As String, ByVal stringValueForField4 As String)
    Dim dataContext as New SampleDataContext
    dataContext.Connection.Open()
    Dim sampleRow As New SampleTable With _
        {.Field1= intValueForField1, _
         .Field2 = shortValueForField2, _
         .Field3 = stringValueForField3, _
         .Field4 = stringValueForField4}

    dataContext.SampleTable.InsertOnSubmit(sampleRow)
    dataContext.SubmitChanges()
    datacontext.Connection.Close()
    dataContext.Dispose()
End Sub
```

*Code simplified for example*

But Linq executes the `INSERT` using `varchar(8000)` parameters:

```
(@p0 int,@p1 smallint,@p2 varchar(8000),@p3 varchar(8000)) INSERT INTO [dbo].[SampleTable]([Field1],[Field2],[Field3],[Field4]) VALUES(@p0,@p1,@p2,@p3)
```

Looking over the internet I found [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a46d676-32f0-44a4-b39f-61a17bccb8e3/parameter-resized-to-varchar-4000?forum=linqtosql) that states it aparently is a bug of Linq to Sql 4, because Visual Studio 2008 creates parameters the same size the fields in the DBML are defined. It eventually turned into [this bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/585759) wich has a closed status and says the bug won't be solved.

Now, althought I don't think this could be causing all the performance problems in our server, could this actually be causing **any** performance problem? Can this change of size cause any impact on the actual query execution? Has anyone had issues with this and/or found a workaround? And more for curiosity than for anything else, is this *bug* solved in more recent versions of Visual Studio? I think this is actually a weird behaviour, and if the issue hasn't been solved, it somehow makes defining the size of the varchar field in the DBML rather useless.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the data is of the same base type this won't cause any performance problems.  But watch out for type conversions ( varchar to nvarchar or nvarchar to varchar) as those can absolutely kill performance.

As for defining the size in the DBML being useless, to an extent it is -- a varchar(max) column with 20 characters in it, takes exactly as much room as a varchar(8000) or varchar(20).  The difference is that the last says something about the acceptable size of the input AND allows efficient indexing (indexes have a 900 character limit).

So, the size of the column has both conceptual **and** performance implications for **tables**, make them the appopriate size.  For local variables in stored procedures or batches there is no performance impact, for parameters there is no performance impact but there are conceptual implications.

For LINQ or any other ORM, don't worry about the size as that is irrelevant, do make sure that the TYPE matches.